# Using for loop to print grid in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, canvas

I am trying to create a small grid for connect four game using a four loop. I have printed circles for X and Y axis but I have only been able to print 1 row successfully, I am trying to print this seven times across the canvas but the for loop I have created does not seem to work.

```
var x = 30;

var y = 30; 

function setup(){

createCanvas(300,300);
background(0);

for(i=0; i<=6; i++){
    for(i=0; i<=6; i++){
        x+=30;
        circle(x, y, 20);
            for(i=0; i<=6; i++){
                y+=30;
                circle(x, y, 20);
        }
    }   
}
    }
    setup();
```

I am trying to achieve this:

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*A5b630g96x9PrhwB9Mvf1w.png]

Comment: are you using same variable for all loops ??

Comment: I am using the same var x and var y variables for all loops

Comment: Note: instead of for loops, you may consider using a pattern for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop structure - iterate 7 times and increase `y` at the end of each iteration, and iterate within this loop where you render the circle, and increase `x`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    x = 30;
    for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        circle(x, y, 20);
        x += 30;
    }
    y += 30;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do have three loops that use `i`, and actually all loops will work on the same number, therefore the inner loop will loop 6times, than all three loops end. As your aim is to loop over x and y, just use them:

```
  for(let x = 1; x < 6; x++) { // always declare variables with let!
    for(let y = 1; y < 6; y++) {
       circle(x * 30, y * 30, 20); // just keep as many varoables as necessary, the position can easily be derived from the index
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 300),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 300),
  cy = ch / 2;
//the circles radius
let ar = 30;
//the red and yellow clees index
let red = [10, 23, 30, 31, 37, 40];
let gold = [16, 17, 24, 32, 38, 39];

let n = 0;// a counter
let cellw = cw / 7;// the width of a cell

//the loop:

  for (let y = cellw / 2; y < ch; y += cellw) {
    for (let x = cellw / 2; x < cw; x += cellw) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ar / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    //set the color of the circles
    for (let i = 0; i < red.length; i++) {
      if (n == red[i]) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        break;
      } else if (n == gold[i]) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "gold";
        break;
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      }
    }
    ctx.fill();
    n++;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there's a problem in the for loop.

You just need to 2 loops for that.

```
for (let row = 0; row <= 6; row++) {
  for (let column = 0; column <= 6; column++) {
    circle(row * 30, column * 30, 20)
  } 
}
```